# Queria fazer um quadrado magico, onde coloco 9 números, e a soma deles tem que resultar 15 (nas horizontais e verticais)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa noite pessoal, eu tenho essa matriz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que os números da matriz somados deem todos `15`.
Tanto na vertical, como na horizontal..

Código:

```
import numpy as np
import random

from tabulate import tabulate 

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

random.shuffle(a)

data = np.reshape(a, (3, 3))

soma_horizontal = []
for lista in data:
    soma_horizontal.append(sum(lista))
soma_vertical = []
for x in range(len(data)):
    soma = 0
    for lista in data:
        soma += lista[x]
    soma_vertical.append(soma)
indice = 0
for lista in data:
    lista.extend(['\u2192', soma_horizontal[indice]])
    indice += 1
setas_cima = ['\u2191'] * 3
data = [soma_vertical] + [setas_cima] + data
print(tabulate(data, tablefmt="grid", stralign='center', numalign='center'))
```

O programa funcionando no repl:

https://repl.it/@William33/UnwillingPopularAndeancondor-3

Comment: Comece por corrigir a indentação da pergunta, que não está correta nem igual ao código que tem no *repl*. Depois está basicamente à procura de um quadrado mágico. Consegue achar uma solução utilizando combinações

Comment: boa noite @Isac eu alterei o nome da pergunta.. será que poderia me ajudar??

Comment: Eu copiei o código que está no rpli-it, mas *não faça mais isso*: A identação em Python não é opcional, o que você tinha colado aí era uma sopa de comandos, e não um programa Python. Use o botão `{ }` para formatar seu código em vez de tentar identar manualmente na edição aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Cara sua dúvida não fica muito clara, se você deseja uma solução para este quadrado mágico(o que é pouco provável), ou um algoritmo que solucionasse tal caso.

- Se você deseja uma solução é simples achar na internet http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/upload/e/Untitled-1(203).jpg
- Se for um algoritmo para solucionar no Wikipédia mostra um pra solução 3x3 que é o seu caso, se quiser extrapolar acredito que com uma busca na internet seja simples encontrar.

**O algoritmo mostrado é o seguinte**

> Dicas para solucionar o quadrado mágico 3x3:
>
> 1. O total que se quer obter em todos os sentidos deverá ser dividido por 3. O que resultará no número a ser colocado no centro do quadrado.
> 2. Os números a serem colocados nos cantos deverão ser pares se o centro for ímpar, ou vice e versa.
> 3. O último número a ser colocado deverá ser o centro mais 4.
>
> Essas regras só valem se os números forem múltiplos de 3. Ex: 15, 18,
>   21, 24, 27, 30 etc.

A partir disso basta implementá-lo.

**Referências**

- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrado_mágico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrado_m%C3%A1gico)
- http://educador.brasilescola.uol.com.br/estrategias-ensino/solucionando-quadrados-magicos.htm